# Appium: How to tap or click at a X/Y co-ordinates

Tags: selenium, java, appium, uiautomation, mobile-automation

My screen size is `(800, 1280)`

I have determained the screen size using:

```
Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
```

Now I want to tab at a given coordinates of the screen so can anyone tell me how to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by tab at point? It doesn't really make sense from a user point of view, especially on a mobile device.

Comment: I just want to tab at any one coordinates, therefore I tried `swipe.tap(startx, starty).perform();` but it isn't working

Comment: Please, Accept the answer which helped you the most. So this question will no longer will be in Active state.

Comment: I didn't get my answer Narendra.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

- You have already found **screen size** by using

`Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();`

- Just to **calculate center point of height** of the screen

`int point_to_tap = (int) (size.getHeight() * 0.5);`

- To **calculate center point of width** of the screen

`int point_to_tap = (int) (size.getWidth() * 0.5);`

- Then you can simply tap providing `point_to_tap` as a parameter

Comment: You Mean by using `swipe.tap(point_to_tap_width, point_to_tap_height).perform();`

Comment: yeah - you can turn it anyway you want to. You can use for swipe, tap, touch. Does it making sense?

Comment: I tried  `swipe.tap(startx, starty).perform();` But it is giving me `NullPointerException`

Comment: Your question is only belongs to finding the co-ordinates. [Ask new question - If needed]
Let me know what actually case you wanted to automate?

Comment: The question is same, I just want to tab at any one coordinates, therefore I tried `swipe.tap(startx, starty).perform();` but it isn't working

Comment: The question is not about finding coordinated. Its about how to click at a given coordinates